# jQuery: Target $(this) and an element

Tags: jquery

On a click I'm removing two elements `$(this)` and `$("#foo")`.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
$(this).remove();
$("#foo").remove();
```

How can I optimize this without repeating myself? I've tried:

```
$(this, "#foo").remove();
```

and

```
$(this "#foo").remove();
```

and

```
$(this && "#foo").remove();
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.add()` to add the current element to the set of matched elements:

```
$('#foo').add(this).remove();
```

I would use the verbose way instead. It's more readable.